Cross sectional area of a 3D geometry with Alpha Shape
I want to obtain the cross sectional area of a geometry (imported as a STL file) for a given group of cutting planes. The figures present some of the points obtained (they are 2D points). Note that the geometry has branches and 'bubbles' inside. I was trying to calculate the area with help of alphashape, but I can't define an alpha that could be used on all cutting planes, or that can define the border of the figures properly. I also tried alphaoptimize without success. In the figures, alpha = 0.3.
Fig. 1
Fig. 2
Fig. 3
I found this approach shared in this question, but, if possible, I'd like to avoid adding more points by creating a volumetric mesh.
Here is how I'm calculating the area for each cutting plane:
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
import alphashape

def CPlane_area(points):
    area = 0
    alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha=0.3)
    if isinstance(alpha_shape, Polygon):
        area = alpha_shape.area
    elif isinstance(alpha_shape, MultiPolygon):
        for polygon in alpha_shape.geoms:
            area += polygon.area
    return area

With alphaoptimize I receive a type error, even though the array points is a numpy array (I think shapely has a interoperability with numpy, but I could be wrong or I'm implementing something wrong).
